# Why am I unable to edit the rating bar on my Samsung Tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, ratingbar

I have created an android application and I am using rating bars in it so that users can rate stuffs. I am able to view the rating bar(Blue stars after I click on them) on my Le-Eco Le1s but when I try the same on my Tab, rating bar is visible, but the stars are filled with black color and on my click nothing has been changed. When I try to rate using this rating bar, record is updated based on my click, but I could not see any changes in the UI. Please help me sort this issue guys!
Regards, 
Thanks.

Comment: Probably something you have to do with your styles.

Comment: Thanks, for replying mate.

Comment: <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/avgRate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileimage"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

Comment: I am using AppCompat Rating bar

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your #appCompat than it will work.
Use latest one.. Otherwise try to change your theme. May be it will work

```
dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"}
```

Comment: I am using this one-> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'

Comment: And the theme I am using is Holo. I also tried DeviceDefault. Both are'nt working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying guys. Finally got the issue resolved. Needed to change the layout XML file to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
.............
.............
 style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"   //Also changed the style to this
/>
```